# random image not working correctly

Tags: php, arrays, explode

i have create an array to diusplay a random file name from my mysql database. unfortunatly it doesnt show correctly.

i need the explode to work based on file id to show the correct banner picturse for that tv series.

```
<?php include '../connect/dbseries.php' ?>
<?php include 'Sbarray.php' ?>
<?php
$names = explode ("|", $row['4']);
 ?>


<center><?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
echo '<a href="episodemenu.php?id='.$row['ID'].'"><img src="../images/series/'. $names[array_rand($names,1)].'" width="800" height="150" style="padding:2px;"></a>';
}

?>
</center>
```

my array page is

```
<?php   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT 
                            ID, 
                            pretty_name, 
                            sortname, 
                            Genre,
                            Bannerfilenames,
                            CurrentBannerFilename,
                            Posterfilenames,
                            PosterBannerFileName, 
                            summary, 
                            Fanart,
                            IMDB_ID

                            FROM online_series

                            order by sortname ASC;");
if (!$result2) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

?>

<?php $row = mysql_fetch_row($result2); 

//setup array
$banner = $row['4'];

?>
```

that is all the code i have on the page. any help would be appreciated as it only shows images from row 1 instead of for each row/ tv series

i asume it has something to do with the explode command but cant figure out how to correct it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can provide more code.. Because if it is all code on the page where is result2 is set? how can the variable row exists in line 4 if it is set in the while loop? Maybe it would be help to know the format of row[4] and how the table is structured.

Comment: sorry my bad i have added the other page for the array now. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check with `print_r($names)` whether it works. If I understand your problem correctly, you want a random pic of each row. Now you do the variable names before you iterating through the results - so it uses always the first:

```
<?php   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT 
                            ID, 
                            pretty_name, 
                            sortname, 
                            Genre,
                            Bannerfilenames,
                            CurrentBannerFilename,
                            Posterfilenames,
                            PosterBannerFileName, 
                            summary, 
                            Fanart,
                            IMDB_ID

                            FROM online_series

                            order by sortname ASC;");
if (!$result2) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
?>
<center><?php 

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
$names = explode ("|", $row['Bannerfilenames']);
//for check whether explode works
print_r($names);
echo '<a href="episodemenu.php?id='.$row['ID'].'"><img src="../images/series/'. $names[array_rand($names,1)].'" width="800" height="150" style="padding:2px;"></a>';
}

?>
```